# Facebook with j2me

Tags: facebook, java-me

I have create a j2me game, now i want to embed Facebook in my App's home page.
so, what should i do for it ?

Comment: Hi PAD, were you able to integrate facebook in j2me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to embed facebook content into non web applications by making use of HTTP API provided by Facebook. For this you will need to sign up as a facebook developer and use those credentials to access the content. More information can be found here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Let us know if you have any specific question.